# TypeError: Cannot redefine property of extended Array declaration

Tags: typescript, typescript-declarations

The following code is extending the global `Array` definition:

```
// array.ts
export {}

declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    binaryIndexOf(e: T, desc: boolean): number
    addSorted(e: T, desc: boolean): T[]
  }
}

if (!Array.prototype.binaryIndexOf) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'binaryIndexOf', {
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    configurable: false,
    value: function binaryIndexOf<T>(this: T[], e: T, desc: boolean) {
...
```

The compiler doesn't complain about missing functions but when I run my code I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot redefine property: binaryIndexOf

   at src/array.ts:36

  34 |
  35 | if (!Array.prototype.addSorted) {
> 36 |   Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'binaryIndexOf', {
     |          ^
  37 |     enumerable: false,
  38 |     writable: false,
  39 |     configurable: false,
```

If I set the `configurable` flag to `true` then another error occurs when trying to invoke `addSorted`

```
TypeError: testData.addSorted is not a function
```

Comment: I see [no such error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXwFCoCbAMYBsCGUwcA5rhAEb66Kpz1wCWAdjMFAGb7bECCUUfAE8APABUAfLQYy4FFoSEBJZlhAB5DgApgALjhiANHCwBnbPooQIuYPmYBKfcwCuAWwrs6s+vgwYAZWg2DB19IxNgc0trW3snAwBtAF1vejQ0VEYOOC0AQn5BIQA6MCgIGAqhMGBi+WZFFTVNB2kGdQoAKxwYYqwOFmAABXKa2CEtQuFS8sqYauBjAHJ6xtVQTSXjBDTZYFc3dnwKW30uXFNF3ZkAdyhGGGPTuHPLw2uGbAhmAZIXQROehe1DeH3oADdqC4gRwXMxsDBGN85AooMp1hoOOIJFoYAALRimcIpYxAiJmCxyWJ2RxtHxoGTIByoNBAA)

Comment: Because you need to create another file that invokes `addSorted` and run

Comment: You're calling `addSorted` but you're only defining `binaryIndexOf`.

Comment: I do, the snippet only contains `binaryIndexOf` so try to run it instead

Comment: Again no problem if the polyfill is run ! https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-mwjpjg?file=index.ts,foo.ts

Comment: You are running in another way, look at this https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-n3e38z?file=index.ts

Comment: Again, `foo.ts` is not run. You have to exeplicitly import that file for it to be run.

Comment: See here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-lf8qqb?file=index.ts,foo.ts with a dummy `test()` call.

Comment: While the obvious answer is to just import array.ts so it runs, I would generally not recommend extending primitive prototypes. It's better to create a function that takes an array as first argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code in `array.ts` probably not run if you do not import it in some way.

You need to find a way to execute that polyfill code.